# Why my ngFor display in one line only show one item with my row and col- class

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this angular app, I'm trying to display some products, but at some point, I don't know why it shows me a row with only one product [image: product]

Html

```
<div class="items-container">
<div class="row">
  <div
    class="col-3 single-item-display"
    *ngFor="let product of products.products"
  >
    <img src="{{ 'assets/img/Products/' + product.img + '.jpg' }}" />
    <div class="item-description">
      <span>{{ product.name }}</span>
      <span>{{ product.price }}$</span>
      <div class="add-remove-item">
        <a
          href="#"
          href="#"
          (click)="
            removeItem(product);
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation()
          "
        >
          <fa-icon [icon]="remove"></fa-icon>
        </a>
        {{ product.quantity }}
        <a
          href="#"
          (click)="
            addItem(product);
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation()
          "
        >
          <fa-icon [icon]="add"></fa-icon>
        </a>
      </div>
      <a
        href="#"
        class="add-to-cart"
        (click)="
          addToCart(product);
          $event.preventDefault();
          $event.stopPropagation()
        "
      >
        Agregar a carrito
      </a>
      <a
        href="#"
        class="buy-now"
        style="margin-top: 10px;"
        (click)="
          buyNow(product); $event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation()
        "
      >
        Comprar
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I got the `css` for the classes `row` and `col-` from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp).

I also tried to make an array of arrays to wrap my `row` class and put the `*ngFor` inside that div, but it didn't have the right width even if I hardcode `width: 100vw`

Comment: The ngFor should probably be on your row. It’s on a col now so it will just keep adding cols..

Comment: the reason could be height of elements. If they are not same then u can get this kind of problems. Can you give fixed height to all items then check if still problem occurs